# How to get keypoint "within the homography"?

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, homography, keypoint

Referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26043637/4480180) answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25992632/opencv-repeatability-result-not-make-sense):

> What is happening is that you're considering all the keypoints
>   detected in the second image for the calculation of repeatability and
>   actually only the keypoints within the homography should be used.

I don't understand how to get the

> keypoints withing the homography

Someone can explain how to do it?

**EDIT:**

Actually looking at the code of `evaluation.cpp` I think that this operation is already performed. In fact, looking at:

```
float overlapThreshold;
bool ifEvaluateDetectors = thresholdedOverlapMask == 0;
if( ifEvaluateDetectors )
{
    overlapThreshold = 1.f - 0.4f;

    // remove key points from outside of the common image part
    Size sz1 = img1.size(), sz2 = img2.size();
    filterEllipticKeyPointsByImageSize( keypoints1, sz1 );
    filterEllipticKeyPointsByImageSize( keypoints1t, sz2 );
    filterEllipticKeyPointsByImageSize( keypoints2, sz2 );
    filterEllipticKeyPointsByImageSize( keypoints2t, sz1 );
}
else
{
    overlapThreshold = 1.f - 0.5f;

    thresholdedOverlapMask->create( (int)keypoints1.size(), (int)keypoints2t.size(), CV_8UC1 );
    thresholdedOverlapMask->setTo( Scalar::all(0) );
}
```

Consider that `thresholdedOverlapMask=0` by default. So the part inside the `if` discard the point outside the homography. Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> keypoints withing the homography
> Those are points that considered as inliers for the result Homograph Matrix. In other words:

Supposing you are using an estimation technique like RANSAC to get your Homograph Matrix, some of your points will be used to construct this Homograph. The others are just a noise(outliers). You need to know which of your points that are not noise and that were used to construct this Homograph.

---

**How to do that in OpenCV?**

The `cv::findHomography` function has the following signature:

```
Mat findHomography(InputArray srcPoints, InputArray dstPoints, int method=0, double ransacReprojThreshold=3, OutputArray mask=noArray() );
```

The parameter `OutputArray mask` is what you are looking for. You can use it like this:

```
std::vector<uchar> homograph_mask;
auto H= cv::findHomography(set_of_points, other_set_of_points, cv::RANSAC, RANSAC_THRESHOLSD, homograph_mask);
std::vector<std::pair<cv::Point,cv::Point>> points_within_the_homograph;
points_within_the_homograph.reserve(homograph_mask.size());
for(size_t i=0; i < homograph_mask.size();++i){
    if(homograph_mask[i]==static_cast<uchar>(1)){
         points_within_the_homograph.emplace_back(set_of_points[i],other_set_of_points[i]);
    }
}
points_within_the_homograph.shrink_to_fit();
```

`points_within_the_homograph` will contain a set of pairs of matched points that are within the Homograph (inliers).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Anyway the signature of the function that the question talks about is `void cv::evaluateFeatureDetector( const Mat& img1, const Mat& img2, const Mat& H1to2,
                              std::vector<KeyPoint>* _keypoints1, std::vector<KeyPoint>* _keypoints2,
                              float& repeatability, int& correspCount,
                              const Ptr<FeatureDetector>& _fdetector )` which seems different from `points_within_the_homograph` that you defined in your answer.

Comment: From what I understood from the linked answer, What I would need is that `_keypoints2` contains only the points within the homography.

Comment: @justHelloWorld in orde to get the points wihting the homography you should use cv::findHomography this another step that should be taken

Comment: Actually looking at the [evaluation.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/features2d/src/evaluation.cpp) code I think that this operation (discard the points that doesn't belong to the common image part) is already done. Look at my **Edit** section

Comment: Could you look please [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37588341/how-can-i-compile-the-evaluation-cpp-in-opencv) question also please?

Comment: The call to `emplace_back()` here contains `set_of_points[i]` twice — should the second one be `other_set_of_points`? Just wondering how it's creating a pair of matched points otherwise, as it looks like it's just going to have 2 references to keypoints1

Comment: @anotherdave definitely! edited, thanks for notifying!