# CV::evaluateFeatureDetector doesn't work?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, descriptor

I want to evaluate some detector

```
#include <opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(void)
{
    //===================VARIABLES==========================
    //input images
        Mat img_1 = imread("data/graf1.png", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
        Mat img_2 = imread("data/graf3.png", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
    //homography matrix
    Mat H1to2;
    FileStorage fs("data/H1to3p.xml", FileStorage::READ);
    fs.getFirstTopLevelNode() >> H1to2;
    //keypoints vector
        vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_1, keypoints_2;
    //decripotrs matrices
    Mat desc1, desc2;
    //SIFT detector
    Ptr<xfeatures2d::SIFT> sift = xfeatures2d::SIFT::create();
    //Descriptor evaluation
    float repeatability;
    int correspCount;
    evaluateFeatureDetector(img_1,img_2,H1to2,&keypoints_1,&keypoints_2,repeatability,correspCount,sift);
    cout<<"repeatability="<<repeatability<<" correspCount="<<correspCount<<" Keypoint 1st="<<keypoints_1.size()<<" Keypoint 2st="<<keypoints_2.size()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the output:

```
repeatability=0.484741 correspCount=953 Keypoint 1st=2667 Keypoint 2st=3498
```

But since the `repeatability=correspCount/min(Keypoint 1st,Keypoint 2st)` the value above is not correct.

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26043637/4480180) a possible cause is explained, but looking how `evaluateFeatureDetector` is implemented in [`evaluation.cpp`](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/features2d/src/evaluation.cpp) (especially `calculateRepeatability`) it seems that this not-common keypoints are already removed:

```
...

if( ifEvaluateDetectors )
{
    overlapThreshold = 1.f - 0.4f;

    // remove key points from outside of the common image part
    Size sz1 = img1.size(), sz2 = img2.size();
    filterEllipticKeyPointsByImageSize( keypoints1, sz1 );
    filterEllipticKeyPointsByImageSize( keypoints1t, sz2 );
    filterEllipticKeyPointsByImageSize( keypoints2, sz2 );
    filterEllipticKeyPointsByImageSize( keypoints2t, sz1 );
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In `evaluation.cpp` at line 429:

```
size_t size1 = keypoints1.size(), size2 = keypoints2t.size();
size_t minCount = MIN( size1, size2 );
```

where `keypoints1` is the actual keypoints in the first image, and `keypoints2t` is the projection of keypoints in the second image on the first image. In other words, `keypoints2t=proj(keypoints2,H^-1)`. Thus, the denominator in the formula might either come from `size(keypoints1)` or `size(projection of keypoints2)`.

In the output line you provided, I assume `correspCount=953`, `size1=2667` and `size2=1966`.

Answer (score 0):

The code of `EvaluateFeatureDetector()` seems to implement exactly the measurements as described in 
*K. Mikolajczyk, T. Tuytelaars, C. Schmid, A. Zisserman, J. Matas, F. Schaffalitzky, T. Kadir, and L. Van Gool. A comparison of affine region detectors. IJCV, 1(65):43–72, 2005.*

They write *"We take into account only the regions located in the part of the scene present in both images."*
Also the normalize the size of the features to a common scale of 30 and accept an overlap error smaller than 40 % as repitition of a feature.

The same criterion is also mentioned in *K. Mikolajczyk and C. Schmid, “Scale & affine invariant interest point detectors,” Int. J. Comput. Vis., vol. 60, no. 1, pp. 63–86, 2004.* But there they also have the criterion that the centeres of the features must not be further away from each other that 1.5 pixels. That I couldn't find in their implementation, but the paper is also older and maybe they redicided about this criterion.

In case you are still interested you may also check out [this](http://www.vlfeat.org/benchmarks/overview/repeatability.html) website, which will lead you also to the original matlab iplementation, which I guess is used by people.